# Problema al eliminar página Magento

Tags: cache, magento, magento-1.9

Elimine una página en Magento desde el dashboard pero aún me aparece cuando la busco. Use incógnito y borre cache desde Magento y desde FTP y nada. Pero otras páginas si borro o modifico si se marca correctamente. Uso la versión Magento 1.9